# Criteria listing query with restriction on sub entity non primary key issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping

I want to use hibernate criteria with restriction on sub entity non key field for listing objects.

**criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("template.orientation", orientation));**

where "template.orientation" is a field in articleTemplate.template

when I am trying to run this the following exception fired.

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: template.orientation of: com.media.web.bean.ArticleTemplate

can you help me?

Comment: Please clarify by showing your entities and their relationship, as well as the code used ti create the Criteria instance.

Comment: Maybe comrad 674714 should also start voting in some of his answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the getters and setters in ArticleTemplate?
ie: `template.getOrientation() and template.setOrientation(Orientation)`?